# Having calculated Form data exist in other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Situation:
I have a calculator that I am building with js. It is a custom function that has two text input fields and when the user clicks a 'Calculate' button it performs 4 different equations and outputs them into 4 separate text input boxes.

Question:
Is there a way to output the answers and input data into non-text input fields, like a string of normal text?

Example:

> Your marketing Budget [$100,000]
> Amount spent locally  [10%]
> 'Calculate Button'
>
> Now by simply allocating [10%] of you annual budget you are able to increase ROI by [X] amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can simply put `<span>`s as placeholders and set their content with `.html()`: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Edit:
As you have provided the function in a comment now, here is a more suited jqueryish example for your case:

```
x=Number($('#nationalBudget').val());
y=Number($('#percentageToLocal').val());
a=x*2;
b=[x*(100/100-(1/y))]*2;
c=(x*(1/y))*4;
$('#idOfSpan1').text(a);
$('#idOfSpan2').text(b);
$('#idOfSpan3').text(c);
```

Comment: I think that .text() will be more appropriate

Comment: So I understand that I can print HTML strings using .html(), but I am just having a hard time wrapping my mind around how I would tie content generated from an input field into my function...         function national(){
x=Number(document.calculatorNational.nationalBudget.value);
y=Number(document.calculatorNational.percentageToLocal.value);
a=x*2;
b=[x*(100/100-(1/y))]*2;
c=(x*(1/y))*4;
document.calculatorNational.total1.value=a;
document.calculatorNational.total2.value=b;
document.calculatorNational.total3.value=c;
}

Comment: But somehow you must have filled the form fields before? Just calculate the values for the fields in the function you call when pressing the button and put those values into the spans or divs with the .text or .html function.

Comment: See my updated answer - and as you have tagged your question with the jquery tag, please use that.

Comment: You're the man...worked like a charm. It's super basic, but since I've never ran it this way I didn't quite get it. Thanks for saving me some time!. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use div with an id for that.

see for example:

http://www.htmlhelpcentral.com/messageboard/showthread.php?7645-document.div.document.write%28%29

or http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/writing